# is area51 for different areas

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, languages

Friends, different country people proposes the site on area51 for their own region or area. This will result in like having Stack Overflow in different languages ! Any solution ?

EDIT : I am not asking the meaning of Area51 ! This is just a discussion of this language-cuticle problem.

Answer (score 2):

It will solve it's self. If enough people actually want it to make the site viable then it will happen through the area51 process, otherwise they will fail. We don't have to make a choice.

Comment: I agree ! But, in case if there will be proposal for "Stack Overflow for My country people only", will you agree ?

Comment: It would likely not make it because it would be to "localized". But if there are enough people to support it then it could make it. Are you asking if I think it is a good idea or if I think it is a viable site?

Comment: True ! I am saying in the sense of viability. It is because the language separation is not allowed with SO itself !